# Combine two MySQL tables in PDO and create CSV output

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

new here. I'll do my best to phrase this question as clearly as possible.

I am building an order database, in that database I have two tables.

Table 1 (orders) has these columns:

```
id, name, datetime
```

Table 2 (items ordered) has these columns:

```
id, orderid, itemname, price
```

`orderid` in table 2 is `id` in table 1

I need to run a MySQL query that outputs an array that looks like this:

`orderid, datetime, name, itemname, price`

This is how I select the orders:

```
$date1 = "2020-09-29"; //$_GET["date1"];
$date2 = "2020-09-30"; //$_GET["date2"];

include 'dbconfig.php';

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:charset=utf8mb4;host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);

$pdo = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, name datetime FROM orders WHERE datetime BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2");

$pdo->execute(['date1'  =>  $date1,
               'date2'  =>  $date2]); 
 
while ($row = $pdo->fetch()) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

and this is how I select the order items:

```
$sql = "SELECT orderid, itemname, price FROM orderitems WHERE orderid=:id";
```

How do I combine them and make them export the array in the way I want?

Answer (score 1):

You can already do the join in SQL and only need to send that *one* query to the database not one for the orders and then one each for the order details. That's way faster. That query would be:

```
SELECT o.id orderid,
       o.datetime,
       o.name,
       oi.itemname,
       oi.price
       FROM orders o
            INNER JOIN ordered oi
                       ON oi.orderid = o.id
       WHERE o.datetime >= :date1
             AND o.datetime < :date2;
```

And don't use `BETWEEN` for timestamp ranges. If your upper bound is 2020-09-30 you'll only get the records from 2020-09-30 00:00:00.000. But you'll miss 2020-09-30 01:01:00.000 for instance. Use `<` for comparing the upper bound and the *next* day, i.e. 2020-10-01, as value.